# How to get base url in grails

Tags: grails

Iam using spring security ui plugin in my 2.4.4 grails application, when i click on the 'Register as a new user' link the url goes like http://localhost:8080/UserManagement/register/register (this is working fine)
but the problem is I have another link in this page like

```
<a href="report">report</a>
```

when I click the above report link the url is goes like http://localhost:8080/UserManagement/register/report . What I want actually is http://localhost:8080/UserManagement/report any way to address this problem?
Do i need to take base url? If so how to take that?

Comment: Please choose the right answer, on any case you should use the Grails link tag, not the HTML anchor tag.

Answer (score 1):

Use g:link e.g.

```
<g:link controller="userManagement" action="report">report</g:link>
```

If the above is used in a userManagement view you can omit the controller

```
<g:link action="report">report</g:link>
```

Answer (score 0):

in g:form you assigned

```
action="usermanagement"
```

so only it goes like that 
use g:link

```
<g:link controller="userManagement" action="report">report</g:link>
```